# How can I make the items in the LazyColumn in the content expand naturally when the bottom sheet expands?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc9B1.png)

When the bottom sheet is extended,

I want hidden contents to unfold through animation.

At this time, I want a natural animation where the height of the Row inside the LazyColumn Item expands and the yellow Stick next to it becomes longer.

[the picture i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWlV0.png)

Below is my code.

```kotlin
    Column {
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 10.dp)
                .animateContentSize()
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            Text(
                text = event.startDateTime.toLocalTime().format(HHmmFormatter),
                style = WappTheme.typography.contentBold,
                color = WappTheme.colors.white,
            )

            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(4.dp)
                    .animateContentSize()
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                    .background(WappTheme.colors.yellow34),
            )

            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start) {
                Text(
                    text = event.title,
                    style = WappTheme.typography.contentRegular,
                    color = WappTheme.colors.white,
                )

                Text(
                    text = event.startDateTime.format(HHmmFormatter) + " ~ " +
                        event.endDateTime.format(HHmmFormatter),
                    style = WappTheme.typography.captionRegular,
                    color = WappTheme.colors.yellow34,
                )

                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = bottomSheetState.currentValue == SheetValue.Expanded,
                    enter = expandVertically(),
                    exit = shrinkVertically(),
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = event.location,
                        style = WappTheme.typography.captionRegular,
                        color = WappTheme.colors.yellow34,
                    )

                    Text(
                        text = event.content,
                        style = WappTheme.typography.captionRegular,
                        color = WappTheme.colors.grayBD,
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        Divider(
            color = WappTheme.colors.gray82,
            thickness = 1.dp,
        )
    }
```

When I did this, I got this result.

[Result gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln078.gif)

It is also unnatural that the text appears as an animation,

Only when the text fully appears, the yellow bar next to it expands and the DIvider below also moves.

Is there an angel who can help me?